# Sense Energy Monitor In Panel Spacing

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Just installed the Sense / Square D Wiser Home energy monitor. The instructions state to leave the energy monitoring box somewhere inside the main panel. My main panel is a bit crowded with ground wires directly touching the sense energy monitoring unit. Any issues with this setup or anything else I should be concerned about?

[image: My panel]

In case anyone is wondering, the extra black and red wires that are clamped are from a generator inlet port. They are going to the first breaker on the right which has a generator interlock kit installed to prevent backfeeding to the utility company. I added the wires into the clamps so I can also measure when I'm running off of generator. This gives me the advantage of knowing precisely how much load I'm using and to keep it under the generator's limits.

Comment: I take it your generator has a floating neutral?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yes sir, unfortunately (or fortunately?) I got the same one that this guy on youtube got, the duramax XP4850EH - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkjjZJgaINA.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see any problem with your setup, using the system to monitor your generator is a good idea. I have done similar with CT,s or current transformers I have my generator looped 4 times through my CT’s since my gauges are analogue I know to divide by 4 when the generator is running depending on your CT’s or what ever they call your clamps you may need to do the same to get better resolution with the generator. (4 times provides a 200 amp reading on my gauges that a 50 amp reading would be hard to tell if 35 or 50)